# AWS CDK S3 Bucket Creation Error - Bucket_Name already exisits

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am new to using CloudFormation / CDK and am having trouble figuring out to deploy my stacks without error.  Currently I am using the python CDK to create a bucket.  This bucket will hold model files and I need to ensure that the bucket deployed in this stack retains data over time / new deployments.  From my initial tests, it seems that if `bucket_name` is not specified, the CDK will randomly generate a new bucket name on deployment, which is not ideal.

Here is the snippet used to create the bucket:

`bucket = aws_s3.Bucket(self, "smartsearch-bucket", bucket_name= 'mybucketname')`

The first time I run `cdk deploy`, there are no problems and the bucket is created.  The second time I run `cdk deploy`, I get an error stating that my S3 bucket already exists. What else is needed so that I can redeploy my stack using a predetermined S3 bucket name?

Comment: What is the version of CDK you are using? If it is an older version, can you try updating to the latest version any try again?

Comment: I am using version 1.31.0 which seems to be the latest version.

Comment: I tried recreating the problem but was not able to. Although, I used TypeScript but the behavior should be same in case of Python. If you are not doing already, can you run a sample stack just to create the bucket?

Comment: Just add - `removalPolicy: cdk.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY` this will cause the bucket the allow be destroyed when destroying the whole stack. I don't know why but every change inside the stack makes the stack thinks that something has changed with the s3 bucket and therefore try to delete it. But, don't worry, I use it in production and as long you don't destroy the bucket your data is safe !!

Comment: Are you making any changes between running cdk deploy?  Are you running destroy of the stack?  When destroying a stack with S3 bucket that has files in it the bucket will not be deleted.  When you try to delpoy again then you would get an error that the bucket already exists.  You can create a base_resources stack that deploys S3 bucket then create another stack that is depend on base_resources stack which then also get deployed.  Then you have an abiltity to destroy/deploy stack 2 but base_resourses stack will not be destroyed

Comment: @Yan I have not destroyed the stack at all yet but I am trying to follow the design pattern you mentioned.  In my initial test, I deployed just the s3 bucket in my stack, and then added a KMS key after.  When I went to deploy with the new KMS asset, I get an error saying they bucket already exists

Comment: @AmitBaranesI added that to my s3.Bucket statement but I am still getting an error  When I deploy the stack, I get a link that says: 'Requested update requires the creation of a new physical resource; hence creating one' and then immediate after it fails because it says my bucket exists already

Comment: Did you figure out what the issue was?

Comment: @Yan - I ended up deleting the bucket and redeploying.  Looking back, the bucket may have been created outside of my stack but I swore it was.  Since deleting and redeploying I have not had issues

Comment: Any resolution to this? I am getting the same problem. When I redeploy I get the error bucket already exists. I do not want to destroy the bucket so setting the removal policy to destroy is not an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, and it was due to the reason that **bucket was already created by me manually earlier for some testing**, NOT by ECS stack initially.
Deleting the bucket definitely makes ECS deployment to work fine, as it did for you and I tested this running the deployment multiple times.
Ensure that no ECS resources are pre-created manually.

The way ECS would identify if it has to re-create a resource is via these tags:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The S3 bucket names are global, it means that if someone else on a different account has chosen this name, it wont work, you should provide a very unique name for your bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this worked for me:

```
    const bucketName = 'MyExistingBucketName'; // Name of the bucket to check

    const existingBucket = s3.Bucket.fromBucketName(this, 'ExistingBucket', bucketName);

    if (!existingBucket.bucketName) {
      const newBucket = new s3.Bucket(this, 'NewBucket', {
        bucketName: bucketName,
        ...etc... etc...
      });
    } else {
      // The bucket already exists so don't do anything 
    }
```

I was frequently destroying and then re-creating my stack and I got tired of manually deleting and empty my bucket